# How can I prevent direct requests to internal microservices

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, microservices

I have implemented a microservice project using(C#, .NET Core, Docker,Ocelot).

Basically I made an API Gateway(with ocelot) which connects requests to internal services and each service is an autonomous project with multiple endpoints.

API Gateway works on port **80** and my internal services which configured in **docker-compose** uses different ports like this:

```
 commenting.api:
    container_name: commenting.api
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ConnectionString=Server=mydb;Port=5432;Database=commentDb;UId=admin;Password=somepass;
      - CustomSerilog__ElasticUri=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - EventBus__EventBusConnection=rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5002:80"
```

The problem I have is that when I run my project I can directly call `http://localhost:5002/api/comment` and get the result but I need to know how to prevent users to call internal services with ports?
Right now I hosted my project in a linux host but in future I will put it on cloud.

Comment: your microservices should probably be behind a firewall, or on a separate network, with only the api-gateway accessible externally.

Comment: @JonasH Thank you, Can you explain more?

Comment: As @JonasH mentioned, once you deploy you microservices the server will only expose the port 80 and probably forwarded to the server ip address , firewall should be configured to only expose that port and once you call another will not be accessible, of course you will be still able to call from the own computer as localhost

Comment: @IvanMendoza Thank you, So whether I host my application on cloud(azure,aws,..) or a linux server, I have to configure firewall to only expose port 80 but It doesn't affect requests to internal services that is made by the system like httpaggregator service.